# How to convert or modify the value of the loop, which is an array, to a string in a dynamic list in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to convert an array into a specially formatted string. I can't get it done because I'm rendering the object dynamically and looping through it:

```
<ul class = "details" v-for = "(value, propertyName) in items[this.index]" :key = "value.id">
    <li>{{value}}</li>
</ul>
```

For example, let's say the rendered values are:

- `['Bob', 'Charlie', 'Annie']`
- `'Richard'`

I want to modify the array, and render it as:

- `'Bob' 'Charlie' 'Annie'`
- `'Richard'`

I have already tried `{{values.join(" ")}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could conditionally use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the `value` based on whether it's an `Array`. Then `{{value.join(' ')}}` should work as you expect:

```html
<li v-if="Array.isArray(value)">{{value.join(' ')}}</li>
<li v-else>{{value}}</li>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {id: 1, names: ['Bob', 'Charlie', 'Annie']},
      {id: 2, names: 'Richard'},
    ],
    index: 0,
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label>Index = 0
    <input type="radio" name="index" v-model="index" value="0">
  </label>
  <label>Index = 1
    <input type="radio" name="index" v-model="index" value="1">
  </label>
  
  <ul class = "details" v-for = "(value, propertyName) in items[this.index]" :key = "value.id">
    <li v-if="Array.isArray(value)">{{value.join(' ')}}</li>
    <li v-else>{{value}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Array can be converted to a String by using any of the following methods:

1- **.toString()**

`['a', 'b', 'c'].toString();`  // 'a,b,c'

2- **Coerce to string**

`['a', 'b', 'c'] + [];` // 'a,b,c'

`['a', 'b', 'c'] + '';` // 'a,b,c'

3- **.join()**

`['a', 'b', 'c'].join();` // 'a,b,c' (defaults to ',' separator)

`['a', 'b', 'c'].join('');` // 'abc'

`['a', 'b', 'c'].join('-');` // 'a-b-c'

4- **JSON.stringify()**

`JSON.stringify(['a', [1], 'b', 'c']);` // '['a', [1], 'b','c']'

5- **Manually**, if can't use built-in method...

```
function arrayToString(arr) {
  let str = '';
  arr.forEach(function(i, index) {
    str += i;
    if (index != (arr.length - 1)) {
      str += ',';
    };
  });
  return str;
}
```